# egit - not authorized

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I just connected to GIT from Eclipse Juno using EGit, and successfully cloned a certain remote repository. During the clone I entered my Github username and password, but chose not to save them.

Then I tried to "Fetch from Upstream". I got this error:

```
https://github.com/biunlp/nlp-lab.git: not authorized
```

I had no chance of entering my username and password...

This is strange since I connected to this repository in order to clone...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Update 2022: In what follows, always use:

- a [App password, *not* your account password](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Announcement-Bitbucket-Cloud-account-password-usage-for-Git-over/ba-p/1948231) (see [blog post](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity)).
  So create your **[app password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/)**.
- a [BitBucket Cloud](https://www.atlassian.com/migration), since [BitBucket server](https://www.atlassian.com/licensing/bitbucket#bitbucket-data-center) will be  discontinued in Feb. 2024.

---

### A. To specify credentials individually for each remote

1. Open Git repositories view,
2. open "`Remotes > origin > <your push url>`"
3. click "Change Credentials..."

[image: push menu]

(From [User Guide - Resource Context Menu](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resource_Context_Menu))

### B. To specify credentials per server

If you want to access multiple repositories on the same server without providing the same credentials multiple times, you may use *.netrc*. With this, eGit will use the configuration you provide.

1. Create a text file called `.netrc` (`_netrc` in Windows) in the user home directory.
2. Add content to the file in this form:

```
    machine my.server1.com
    login yourUserName
    password yourPassword

    machine my.server2.com
    login yourUserName
    password yourPassword
```

The Stash documentation contains [more information about .netrc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories#PermanentlyauthenticatingwithGitrepositories-Usingthe.netrcfile)

**Security issue** The problem with using `.netrc` this way is that the password is visible in plain text. Refer to [this answer in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github/18362082#18362082) to solve that problem.

---

More secure option (2022): EGit (from [issue 441198](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441198)) can be made (with an extension) to recognize a native Git credential helper, using a secure encrypted cache:

- install a [native Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
- install the [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager), which is cross-platform, and already package with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) for instance.
- instruct EGit to look for credentials in the GCM: [`gitflow-incremental-builder/gitflow-incremental-builder`](https://github.com/gitflow-incremental-builder/gitflow-incremental-builder)
- register your password or token in said GCM

  ```
  printf "Host=my.server1.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=yourUsername1\npassword=passwd1" | \
  git credential-manager-core store  
  # and:  
  printf "Host=my.server1.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=yourUsername1\npassword=passwd1" | \
  git credential-manager-core store
  ```

Look for executable `git-credential-manager-core`, and add its folder to your `%PATH%`/`$PATH`.

Comment: Ah, those hidden paths... :)

Comment: @VonC, you're the BOMB! I spent way more time on this craziness than I needed to with the ssh keys, yada yada...

Comment: Finally, a clear set of instructions on how to restore things to a working state!

Comment: Thanks!  I spent hours on this problem and this solved it.  Should have searched StackOverflow sooner.  :(

Comment: I had the same problem, but when I disabled 2 factor authentication everything worked. Anyone had this?

Comment: @george_h Yes. You can apparently use a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) to use EGit via HTTPS. ~~I'm trying to work the details out myself.~~ I've just figured it out and will add an answer.

Answer (score 43):

You can try:

> eclipse/myeclipse > menu
>
> window > preferences > general > security >
>
> content > click "delete" > ok

Comment: This is an efficient solution as it fixed all my Eclipse workspaces at once.

Answer (score 34):

**If you're using Two Factor Authentication on GitHub, the "not authorized" error can be returned even if you are using the correct username and password**. This can be resolved by [generating a personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/).

After generating the secure access token, we'll use this instead of a password. Make sure not to leave the page before you're done, because once you leave the page, you'll never see it again (thankfully it can be regenerated, but anything using the previously generated token will cease to authenticate).

This assumes that you've successfully installed EGit and that you've successfully cloned a repository.

1. Go to your GitHub.com settings, and in the left hand pane click `Personal access tokens`.
2. Click `Generate new token`. Select the scopes that you'd like this token to be able to use, and generate it.
3. Copy the token. It should look something like this:  `9731f5cf519e9abb53e6ba9f5134075438944888` (don't worry, this is invalid).
4. Back in Eclipse (Juno, since that's OP's version), click `Window > Show View > Other...`. Under `Git`, select `Git Repositories`.
5. A new pane appears, from which you can open `(repository name) > Remotes > origin`.
6. Right click on a node and choose `Change Credentials...`. Enter your username for `User`, and your secure access token for the `Password`.

Comment: Does it Work fine, just login anc create your token in https://github.com/settings/tokens

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem when I changed my password on the remote repository.

Here is how I fixed it on Eclipse on Mac:

Important Note: These instructions have the side effect of clearing all passwords and other secure information.  I was fine with that, but you will want to consider that before you follow these instructions.

1. Click Eclipse -> Preferences on menu.
2. Expect a popup window called Preferences.
3. Expand the "General" tree item.
4. Double click the "Security" tree item.
5. Expect the main pane of the popup to change to "See 'Secure Storage' for..."
6. Click 'Secure Storage'.
7. Expect the main pane to change to tabbed window.
8. Click the "Contents" tab.
9. Click "Delete".
10. Accept a warning that all your secure information is deleted.
11. Click "Cancel" or "Apply" to exit the popup window.
12. Click the 'Git Pull' icon and expect to be prompted for username and password.

Comment: This answer has received two down votes.  If you down vote please add a comment why.

Comment: I didn't down vote, I guess they did it because it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me my password got reset and I was trying to find out how it can be changed in e-GIt.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Go to Git profile-> Settings -> developer settings-> personal access tokens
delete if any existing token and generate a new token [provide note, specify no.of days and repo checked] ->Copy the new token generated
Goto eclipse and now when the same login prompt appears, try providing the personal token generated as password instead of Git password.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication. From march 2022.

So use app password. Please read more information on below links.

- [Bitbuckect Announcement](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Announcement-Bitbucket-Cloud-account-password-usage-for-Git-over/ba-p/1948231)
- [Bitbuckect blog](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity)
- [App password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/)

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse pushes to Azure Devops it worked when used username and PAT (Personal Access Token, not password) as credentials.