# Eclipse can't connect to Git remote repository with "not authorized" message

Tags: eclipse, git, tfs, egit

I'm using the egit plugin, and while I'm trying to do team -> Pull for a java project in Ecplise, already imported from a remote Git repository, I get the following error stack strace after I enter my credentials :

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: http://server:8080/tfs/project: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PullOperation$1.run(PullOperation.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PullOperation.execute(PullOperation.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.pull.PullOperationUI.execute(PullOperationUI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.pull.PullOperationUI.access$0(PullOperationUI.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.pull.PullOperationUI$1.runInWorkspace(PullOperationUI.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: http://server:8080/tfs/project: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1236)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:239)
    ... 10 more
```

Here is my session data :

```
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

What could be causing this problem ? I've already searched this but found no clear solution

Comment: For the one who downvoted the question, can you say why ?

Comment: Did you clone the repo with a Egit? is it possible your account is blocked due to failed attempts? try to clone the repo with another tool to verify your credentials are still working. Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259265/egit-not-authorized) just in case.

Comment: What's the auth type on your TFS Server?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your github account and create a new Personal access token (Settings/Developer settings) and use it while authentication dialog to enter username and password comes.
Give the token in place of the password.
Your push would happen.
Before that enable 2 factor authentication for your github account too.